# What would a room full of six month old skeletons smell like?

Tags: science-based, biology, humans, death

I'm sure six months of decomposition, even in an enclosed, low-humidity space, will have the bodies reduced to dry skeletons. **By then, would you still have the classic dead body stench that sends characters recoiling?** Or would it be more of a *subtly* putrid odor characterized by specific components of the smell?

Imagine a factory floor-sized space, enclosed, in a desert environment with 3 to five bodies. Heat is the kind of warm that would have you breaking a slight sweat walking around the block but not enough to leave you drenched. Almost zero humidity.

We're talking on full-on skeletons right? What would the smell be like?

Comment: This question don't look like one about worldbuilding. Also what reasearch you made that made you think that low-hum, desert like enviroemnt would make decomposition possible and not mumification?

Comment: Bad. It would smell bad. Even under those conditions, you wouldn't eliminate all traces of flesh in six months.

Comment: 6 weeks, 6 months,  it depends what's been eating the flesh.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np0hJGKrIWg